# Cordova ios project missing cordova.js

Tags: ios, cordova, platform

I have a cordova ios project that I created a while ago with cordova 2.8.x and now I have updated cordova to 3.3.1

The problem is that when I execute cordova build, no cordova.js file gets created. I've played around with cordova 3.3.1 and it seems that the cordova.js file is created when the platform is added.

I've already have added the platform from before, how can I create the cordova.js file for ios without readding the ios platform?

Comment: As noone answered yet I'll write it, but it's just a guess: try to run `phonegap local build ios` in the terminal, maybe that will do the trick

Comment: A'm not using phonegap, just cordova.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your project with `phonegap create myApp` it creates it with phonegap.js instead of cordova.js

You can try `cordova platform add <your platform>` e.g. `cordova platform add ios` should add cordova.js to your project.

Also, make sure your index.html `<script>` is referencing the correct file after doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

just take care of building your project because if you build your project using:

```
phonegap local build ios
```

**phoengap.js** file will be generated but if you build it using:

```
cordova build ios
```

**cordova.js** file will be generated